# str_replace can you please explain why this happens?

Tags: php

Can you please help me understand this code?

```
  $turl = get_bloginfo('home');

  if ( $lang_current == "en" OR "ru" ) {
    $location = str_replace ($turl,$turl."/".$lang_current,$location);
  }


return $location;
```

I don't understand why, even if `$lang_current == "ka"` Why do I still get str_replace activated?

I'm expecting this code str_replace to work only when languages are en or ru, if any other language is used I need it just to return $location... but this is not what happens! It is driving me nuts as I don't understand it.

Comment: use `$lang_current == "en" OR $lang_current == "ru"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ru" is always true... you need to put

```
  if ( $lang_current == "en" OR $lang_current == "ru" ) {
```

or:

```
  if ( in_array( $lang_current, array ( "en", "ru" ) ) ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

The string "ru" will evaluate to 1 (true) as you're not comparing the string against anything. Essentially, you are doing the following:

```
if ( ($lang_current == "en") OR ("ru") ) {
```

You'll need to compare to $lang_current on both sides of the OR operand:

```
if ( $lang_current == "en" OR $lang_current == "ru" ) {
```